# How can I reply to a Telegram bot programmatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram

How can I reply and send message programmatically to a Telegram bot using Telegram API or JavaScript?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.